# Python format a string date to actual format gives me error

Tags: python, django

Trying to update the startdate resulted in an error.

Code:

```py
startdate = '2022-12-20 10:18:00+00:00'
date_format_str = "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S%z"
starttime = datetime.strptime(startdate, date_format_str)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-12-20 10:18:00+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S%z'
```

Comment: Show us `startdate`.

Comment: @JohnGordon it's right there in the error message.

Comment: The format string has year-day-month, but the date string has year-month-day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the day and month format codes, as @John Gordon notes. Fortunately, the format of your variable `startdate` is exactly the specific ISO-8601 compliant format that `datetime.fromisoformat()` can parse, so you didn't need to bother:

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: startdate = "2022-12-20 10:18:00+00:00"

In [3]: datetime.fromisoformat(startdate)
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 20, 10, 18, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks a ton to John and  @ddejohn, I had messed up the standard format and only realised it now after I checked your answer.